# How can I get the dates from this nested list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My data contains nested lists and I am trying to create a list that contains only the date information from the second layer of nested lists.

```
"DateMap": {
    "2020-12-04:0": {
      "55.0": [
        {
        }]},
    "2020-12-11:7": {
      "60.0": [
        {
        }]}
  }
```

I want to get a list that is like this `mylist = ["2020-12-04:0", "2020-12-11:7"]`

I have looked into using regex and list comprehensions and this is the expression I have found to match the dates `^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d:\d\d?$`

How can I make this work?

Comment: You call it list, it looks like a dict, and you talk about it as if it's a string. Huh?

Comment: Regex? Why no parser json?

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you. This is so that others can see that the problem is resolved, and so others can find the solution more easily.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `.keys()`. This just gets all the keys of a dictionary, which is exactly what you're looking for. If DateMap is inside a dictionary, say `dic`, just do the same thing for `dic["DateMap"]`.

```
DateMap = {
    "2020-12-04:0": {
      "55.0": [
        {
        }]},
    "2020-12-11:7": {
      "60.0": [
        {
        }]}
  }

mylist = DateMap.keys()
# mylist = list(DateMap.keys()) for Python 3

print(mylist)
# Prints ['2020-12-04:0', '2020-12-11:7']
```

Comment: Question is tagged as [tag:python-3.x].

Comment: @superbrain ...could you explain what that has to do with my answer?

Comment: @superbrain I see. I'll adapt it for Python 3.

Comment: Worked perfect. Thank you. Ill take this as the accepted answer in 2 minutes.